# Adding another arg to comments_popup_link

Tags: comments, translation, localization

what WordPress core functions do I have to modify to change

```
comments_popup_link('Ni komentarjev', '1 komentar','% komentarjev')
```

to

```
comments_popup_link('Ni komentarjev', '1 komentar', **'2 komentarja',** '% komentarjev')
```

I'd like to add an argument for 2 comments. And what lines to add to this functions?

The reason why would I want to do that is simply the fact that in my home language we start plural by 3. I want it to be spelled correctly.

Comment: You can't - you'll have to make a duplicate of that function and add that functionality

Comment: Yes, but which function to duplicate and how to add that functionality. I was searching across the net and according to CatsWhoCode website, to replace core function you use filters

Comment: This is located in your theme's files, so simply alter them (in a child theme possibly), the only filter that is available inside `comments_popup_link()` is `comments_popup_link_attributes` which is not quite useful in your case; where is that line of yours located again?

Answer (score 1):

Filter `'comments_number'`. You get the translated number and the real number as arguments. Return what fits best.

Sample code:

```
add_filter( 'comments_number', 'wpse_31328_comments_number_i18n', 10, 2 );

function wpse_31328_comments_number_i18n( $text, $number )
{
    if ( 2 === $number )
    {
        return _x( '2 comments', 'comments number', 'your_text_domain' );
        // or hard coded:
        // return '2 komentarja';
    }

    return $text
}
```